Google analytics not assigning to traffic acquisition
I'm facing a problem with custom events sent to Google Analytics. The main problem is that custom sent events are being assigned only to user acquisition and not to traffic acquisition.
I'm sending 2 custom events.
1st event starts the session:
{
    "client_id": "435384.2118427612",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "session_start_test",
            "params": {
                "session_id": 1733217977,
                "source": "Test source",
                "medium": "cpc",
                "session_number": 1
            },
            "timestamp_micros": 1733217976999990
        }
    ]
}

2nd event send source data:
{
    "client_id": "435384.2118427612",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "custom_event_test",
            "params": {
                "session_id": 1733217977,
                "engagement_time_msec": 100,
                "title": "Test title",
                "country": "Estonia",
                "source": "Test source",
                "medium": "cpc",
                "campaign": "test",
                "campaign_source": "Test source",
                "campaign_medium": "cpc",
                "session_number": 2
            },
            "timestamp_micros": 1733217977000000
        }
    ],
    "user_properties": {
        "country": {
            "value": "Estonia"
        }
    }
}

Both events are sent to GA and can be seen inside realtime reporting.
The problem that both of these events still assign source/medium to user acquisition instead of traffic acquisition. I've also tried to send utm_source and utm_medium, but that did not work out. Any ideas where is the problem?
I'm sending both events with PHP curl, using Google Measurement Protocol API.
